# Display element coordinate system using Ansys Mechcanical APDL

Tags: ansys, ansys-apdl

Is there any way to display element coordinate system in ANSYS Mechanical APDL GUI (the same way the global coordinates system is displayed)?

Comment: Any idea? Anyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the menu *PlotCtrls > Symbols*, you can find the following window where the option *ESYS Element coordinate sys* you are looking for is available.

[image: Symbols window]

As previously answered, it's also available via the following command:

```
/psymb,esys,1 ! or 0 to remove it.
```

You can look for `/help,/psymb` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer for yor question can be the following command.
/PSYMB,ESYS,1

You can find further information in the software, through Help>Mechanical APDL>Command Reference>XVII. P

Tamás